# PHP/MySQL - Articles out of DB need to be sorted into groups by year

Tags: php, mysql

For a website I need to have some articles. They will be split up in groups of a year. So a group 2017, 2018, etc. Since I am not good at PHP, it took me a while to work these possible solutions up (And my friend tried helping me, unfortunately, his ideas didn't work either).

I tried multiple things to achieve this, for example:

1.

```
public function  fetch_all() {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(action_time,'%d-%m-%17'))");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

2.

```
public function  fetch_all() {
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy, article_timestamp) ");
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

3.

```
<ol>
    <?php if(date('y', $articles['article_timestamp']) == 2017) { foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="publications.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id'] ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title'] ?></a>

             - <small>posted <?php echo date("d-m-'y", $article['article_timestamp'])?></small>
        </li>
    <?php } } ?>
</ol>
```

All of these resulted in nothing being echo'd out as List items for the .

Comment: Whatever is `%17` in your `DATE_FORMAT` call? As a note MySQL, and SQL in general, prefers the `YYYY-MM-DD` ISO-8601 notation, which is what you should be using in queries and when storing data in a proper `DATE` column. Conversion should be done in your application layer if necessary.

Comment: Hint: Order by date, then when displaying them, have a variable that keeps track of the last year shown. If the year changes, display a header. This is a general-purpose solution that will work for any data that's in order.

Comment: `ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy...` DATEPART is a SQL-server function and not a MySQL function

Comment: have you tried `order by year(article_timestamp)` ?

Comment: you can also do `where year(now())=year(article_timestamp)` which would be the current year

Comment: @snitch182 Well I also need to keep record of the older ones, so that has limited use for this project.

Comment: there is the part missing where you fill `$articles`

Comment: @tadman I tried 2017, didn't work, so I thought maybe %17 would, was worth the try. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @snitch182 It's not, it's just not displayed in the part I showed you, sorry. It's  $articles = $article->fetch_all(); and $article is a new object of class Article.

Comment: A noble effort, but do be careful when trying random things, especially in a database environment. The documentation for a function should outline, in very specific terms, what operations are supported. Remember MySQL doesn't ask for confirmation when you type `DROP DATABASE important_production_data`, so be careful.

Comment: I would `print_r($articles);` before the if. I think that the structure in the if needs to be checked.

Comment: @tadman I'll certainly keep that in mind!